# Looking for a faceted navigation tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, faceted-search

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that explains how to build a faceted search structure with ajax , php , and mysql?

Comment: It might be useful that you explain the common user how you understand *faceted search structure* by adding some code what you did so far and how your database structure looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a complete answer for your particular question (because it doesn't address AJAX), but in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256405/faceted-search-solr-vs-good-old-filtering-via-php), netcoder's answer has a simple concept starter for a basic MySQL schema and queries for simple faceted search in PHP.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I actually implemented it since I asked this. I ended up with an array in JavaScript. The values get pushed to the array and I use the array as parameters in a URL that gets requested via ajax. The response is a json object.

Comment: Hey, great!  That sounds clear and concise.  If you feel like posting a few more details, seeing how different people approach the problem can be enlightening.

Comment: are you suggesting I edit my question with the solution I came up with?

Comment: Not exactly ... but you could answer your own question, which is culturally appropriate on StackExchange sites - especially if your answer is better than anyone else's, and it sounds like it's probably pretty good!