# Can some help me in implementing Faceted search in PHP

Tags: php, sphinx, faceted-search

I am trying to build a faceted search for a PHP based e-commerce website. Building filters using `GET` methods is making code very complicated as the website has many filters. Can someone give some tutorial or some better way for building a faceted search?

I thought of implementing faceted search using Sphinx, but I am new to Sphinx. The client has rejected Sphinx (I don't know why). I am able to build basic search using Sphinx, but don't know how to go ahead with faceted search. If someone can provide some tutorials on Sphinx that will be great as I may try to convince the client after implementing using it. Time is a major factor here as I have to implement faceted search in a day.

```
$urlstring = '';
$urlstring = rmParamQS('category');
$urlstring = rmParamQS('brand', $urlstring);
```

code that will add the new query string like category or brand and will remove existing query strings from above functions

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?page='.$page.$urlstring;

$categoryGet = (isset($_GET['category']))?$_GET['category']:NULL;
$categoryQS = '&category='.$categoryGet;

$brandGet = (isset($_GET['brand']))?$_GET['brand']:NULL;
$brandQS = '&brand='.$brandGet;

$categories = categories_list($brandGet);

echo '<ul id="categories">';
list all categories using foreach with link in following format
echo '<a href="'.$url.'&category='.$category["category_id"].'">'
echo '</ul>';

$brands = brands_list($categoryGet);
echo '<ul id="brands">';
list all brands using foreach with link in following format
echo '<a href="'.$url.'&brand='.$brand["brand_id"].'">'
echo '</ul>';
```

Like categories and brands I have five more filters. The rmParamQS function will remove the respective query string from $url. the categories_list and brands_list functions will filter data based on ids in Query Strings in url of other filters

Comment: you probably shouldn't use Sphinx if the client emphatically rejected it

Comment: Actually client has rejected it because of time constraint

Comment: so why are you asking for Sphinx tutorials?

Comment: If only if I can implement it quick enough as I felt Sphinx will be fast and better way to go ahead

Comment: Is a hosted search service an option? It might solve the time constraint

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's a faceted search but here is an example with php and mysql using joins: [Faceted Search (solr) vs Good old filtering via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256405/faceted-search-solr-vs-good-old-filtering-via-php).

Comment: Actually I am able filter the data with database queries in some functions. I am having problem with many GET methods in url while calling these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on faceted search in Sphinx / Manticore Search - https://play.manticoresearch.com/faceting/